# Does there exist a function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^{\star} } t^nf(t)dt=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

Let $f\in C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ such that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} t^nf(t)dt=0$ for all integer n.
We know that $f\equiv 0$. It's "easy" to prove with Weierstrass theorem or with [How to prove that $\,\,f\equiv 0,$ without using Weierstrass theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673698/how-to-prove-f-equiv-0-without-weierstrass-theorem)

- This theorem is wrong on $\mathbb{R^+}$, we can choose :
  $$f(x)=\exp(-x^{\frac{1}{4}})\sin(x^\frac{1}{4})$$

Let 
$$
I_n=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^n\exp(-\omega t)dt=\frac{n!}{\omega^{n+1}},\quad n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad \omega=exp(\frac{i\pi}{4})
$$
Proof.
$$
|t^n\exp(-\omega t)|=t^n\exp \bigr(\frac{-t \sqrt{2}}{2}\bigl)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})
$$
by integration by parts we get 
$$
I_n=\frac{n}{\omega}I_{n-1}
$$
Thus,

### $$
I_n=\frac{n!}{\omega^{n+1}}
$$

Plus for $n\geq 1$, $\quad \omega^{4(n+1)}=-(1)^{n+1}$

Then, 
$$
I_{4n+3}\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Therefore, 
$$
0=\Im(I_{4n+3})=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx
$$

---

- Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$,

I would like to prove the *existence* of a function $f$ such that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^n f(t)dt=0$,

> In fact this example it's not mine (I have already read it in a book) and the question is **to find** $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So I would like to know if we can proove the existence more generally or just how can I construct a such function.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question: you have an example but you are not happy with it because you don't see where it is coming from? So you would like to know how you could have found it by yourself?

Comment: @Etienne Is exactly that except here we  need  $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. In 'my' example $f$ value is not in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Usually, one would say that if $f$ is real-valued, it is in particular complex-valued.

Comment: @Etienne I know that but perhaps we can found f with complex-valued, anyway do you have an idea to found it by myself ? (real-valued, complex-valued , it doesn't matter)

Comment: Right now, I don't know. But this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

Start with your example, take the imaginary part, just user every fourth step with variable $t=s^{1/4}$.  We get:
$$
F(s) = \exp(-s^{1/4})\sin(s^{1/4}),
$$
for which
$$
\int_0^\infty s^n F(s)\;ds = 0
$$
for all nonnegative integers $n$.