# Why does $E[X^ku(X)]=0, \space \forall k \in \Bbb{N}$ imply $u(X)=0$?

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

I am given a situation where
$X_1,X_2,...X_n \sim_{iid} X$ with pdf $f_X(x;\theta)$ and $u(X)$ is an unbiased and sufficient estimator of $\theta$.

I am working on proofs where I am trying to find if $X$ is complete and it seems that as long as

$E[u(X)]=0$ is given and you can show that $E[X^ku(X)]=0$ for any natural number $k$ then you can show $u(X)=0$.

I do not know why the last logic works.

May I have some help please?

Comment: What kind of integrability assumptions do you have on $X$ and $u$?

Comment: I was not given any information that would answer your question, but I am not working with any "special situation" where we are working with unusual distributions.  So far, I have seen this same explanation with exponential distribution, normal distribution and Poisson distribution so I cannot imagine there being any issues with integrability.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1273901/36150) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1692322/36150) are related questions. By assumption, $E(p(X)u(X))=0$ for any polynomial $p$ and under suitable assumptions this gives $E(g(X)u(X))=0$ for any continuous function $g$. This in turn gives $E(1_B(X) u(X))=0$ for any measurable set $B$; now consider $B=\{u>0\}$ and $B=\{u<0\}$.

Comment: I see.  It looks like it is in the field of real analysis.  Unfortunately it is beyond my understanding and I cannot proceed from here, but it does seem to be a fact that is well supported and used.  For now I will accept this as a fact that I have to use blindly.