# If $\int_{0}^{\pi}t^{n}f(t)dt=0$ for all $n\in\{0\}\cup \mathbb N$ then prove that $f \equiv0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals, continuity

> Let, $f:[0,\pi ]\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$.
>
> If $\int_{0}^{\pi}t^{n}f(t)dt=0$ for all $n\in\{0\}\cup \mathbb N$ then prove that $f \equiv0$.

Since, $f$ is continuous & $t^{n}$ is also continuous & $t^{n}$ keeps the positive sign throughout the interval $[0,\pi]$,  so using $1^{st}$ Mean-Value-Theorem of Integral calculus $\exists$  $\xi\in [0,1]$ such that, $$\int_{0}^{\pi}t^{n}f(t)dt=f(\xi)\int_{0}^{\pi}t^{n}dt=f(\xi).\dfrac{\pi^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

Using given condition we get $\exists$  $\xi \in[0,1]$  such that, $f(\xi)=0.$ From here how we can conclude that $f\equiv0$ ?

Or any other way to prove this?

Comment: [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858441/assume-that-f-%E2%88%88-la-b-and-int-xnfxdx-0-for-n-0-1-2?lq=1) question and a solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673698/how-to-prove-f-equiv-0-without-weierstrass-theorem) avoiding W-approx thm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Weierstrass approximation (by polynomials) of continuous functions in compact interval and $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} f^2(t)\,dt = 0 \implies f = 0$, tell me if you need more details.

Comment: I want details & where $f(0)=0$ need?

Comment: @Panja.S. If $f(0) = 0$ we may approximate $f$ with a polynomial $P(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^k$ (i.e., without constant terms) uniformly in the interval $[0,\pi]$. I'll add more steps in the solution.

Comment: @Panja.S. sorry (should have noticed this before) [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858441/assume-that-f-%E2%88%88-la-b-and-int-xnfxdx-0-for-n-0-1-2?lq=1) from the related column.

Comment: If $t^{n}$ is replaced by any other continuous function (like as $\sin x$, $\cos x$ ect.. then are the results valid?

Comment: @Panja.S. The basis needs to satisfy a few properties see [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: How can you do that? Can you please add more steps?